# How to register an event in Powershell so it stays permanent?

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I have the below script, that is just supposed to monitor a folder, and when a .xlsx file is created, then it should convert it to a .csv file in another folder. It works on the first file created, but it doesn't work on the next file being created in the folder. How can I get the event to stay permanent?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$folder = 'c:\Users\exgtcl\hotfolder'
$destination = 'c:\Users\exgtcl\targetfolder'
$filter = '*.xlsx'                

Function Convert-Csv
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$FullPath
    )
    $ExcelFiles = Get-ChildItem $FullPath
    Write-Host "Working on file '$FullPath' "
    $excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excelApp.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $excelApp.Visible = $false
    $workbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFiles.FullName)
    $newName = "$destination\output.csv"
    $workbook.SaveAs($newName, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlCSV)

    $workbook.Close()
    # Release Excel Com Object resource
    $excelApp.Workbooks.Close()
    Start-Sleep 2
    $excelApp.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelApp) | Out-Null
}

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $false              
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$action = {
 $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
 $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
 $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
 Convert-Csv -FullPath $path
 Start-Sleep 3
 Write-Host "moving files"
 Move-Item $path -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose 
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action $action
```